# Can I install on 2 separate storage devices?

Tags: system-installation

I have a netbook, a flash drive (512MB), and an SD card (512MB) and the Ubuntu netbook edition is 696MB, is there any way I can put half of the installation on the flash drive and the other half on the SD card, and get it installed?

Comment: No you will destroy the universe if you attempt this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As got answered in "[Is there an iso of ubuntu under 512MB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23426/is-there-an-iso-of-ubuntu-under-512mb)", [Ubuntu minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) is very likely to be a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, yes, using LVM, that will allow you to create a logical volume that uses your two physical volumes.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#LVM%20Installation%20Guides

Comment: I'm not sure what LVM is, care to explain or give a link to where I can figure out how to do it?

Comment: Sure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#LVM%20Installation%20Guides

Comment: The downside to LVM striping is if you remove that little SD card, your system volume will be unusable.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with the Minimal Cd Image. Choose the platform you want and make a booteable USB Drive with the image. The installation will download all the required and updated files to install whatever linux distribution you want in the platform you choose. It takes longer, since all the data is downloaded from the internet, but at the end you wont need to update your fresh installation. Check it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD